# What is the datatype of this Python variable: node (Abstract Syntax Tree)

Tags: c#, python, parsing, interpreter

I'm building my own interpreter in C# using [Ruslan Pavik's Guide](https://ruslanspivak.com/lsbasi-part7/). I am at part 7 where we are creating an Abstract Syntax Tree. I was able to get by the first parts and was able to translate the Python code in the guide into C#. But in Part 7, it became entirely difficult for a guy with no Python experience.

I am having difficulty figuring out what the datatypes and the return types are, with Python being a dynamic programming language.

I am confused on this part:

```
 def visit(self, node):
    method_name = 'visit_' + type(node).__name__
    visitor = getattr(self, method_name, self.generic_visit)
    return visitor(node)
```

1. I don't know the datatype for `visitor` but I think it's a string.
2. `visitor` gets assigned `getattr` although I don't know what object it tries to get the attribute from.
3. I don't know what datatype does `node` have.

Later on in the guide, he declares this class:

```
class AST(object):
pass
```

But I know that in C# it's just a class with nothing inside the braces: `public class AST { }`.

The next class after `AST` is the `BinOp` that inherits `AST`:

```
class BinOp(AST):
def __init__(self, left, op, right):
    self.left = left
    self.token = self.op = op
    self.right = right
```

Basically I'm really confused right now. But my main confusion is the `node` since I don't know what datatype it has. Since a lot of classes in the parser and interpreter use `node`, I really can't go forward in my interpreter without knowing what datatype it has.

Comment: What is your issue with inheriting an empty class? The `AST` class is basically just used as a “common basis name”.

Comment: I am doing the same thing but in java and had the same problem with the same method. See the answer I was given, it should help - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40601211/visitor-pattern-for-interpreter-invoking-method-based-on-instance-type/40601308#40601308

Answer (score 0):

`node` is an instance of a subclass of `AST` here. `visitor` is a method on a subclass (which you are supposed to write yourself) of the `NodeVisitor` class. It is looked up *dynamically* because the passed in `node` is going to be any one of the possible subclasses of `AST`, and you are expected to implement specific `visit_` methods for specific nodes on your custom subclass. The fallback is to use the `self.generic_visit` method.

`AST` is the base class for nodes. `BinOp` is a specific node class; the different classes are [documented in the *Abstract Grammar* section](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#abstract-grammar); each camel-cased name is also an `AST` subclass.

By looking up methods dynamically by the name of the specific node, the developers avoided having to create specific concrete methods for every node type that the grammar defines.

To make this a little more concrete: say you are interested in specific `BinOp` operator nodes; perhaps because you want to analyse how `+` is used in a piece of code.

You can then implement a `NodeVisitor` subclass, and add a `visit_BinOp()` method on that subclass, and it'll be called automatically when you pass in a *tree* of nodes to `NodeVisitorSubclass().visit(toplevel_node)`; for any nodes for which there is no specific `visit_*` method present, the `NodeVisitor.generic_visit()` method will make sure the child nodes of the tree are visited (through the `iter_fields()` function).

Demo:

```
>>> import ast
>>> class DemoVisitor(ast.NodeVisitor):
...     def visit_BinOp(self, binop_node):
...         if isinstance(binop_node.op, ast.Add):
...             print('Found addition of {} and {}'.format(
...                 ast.dump(binop_node.left), ast.dump(binop_node.right)))
...
>>> tree = ast.parse('function(foo + bar)', '', 'eval')
>>> ast.dump(tree)
"Expression(body=Call(func=Name(id='function', ctx=Load()), args=[BinOp(left=Name(id='foo', ctx=Load()), op=Add(), right=Name(id='bar', ctx=Load()))], keywords=[]))"
>>> DemoVisitor().visit(tree)
Found addition of Name(id='foo', ctx=Load()) and Name(id='bar', ctx=Load())
```

In the above demo, the `NodeWalker.visit()` method found the `visit_BinOp` method and called it for us, but since there are no `visit_Expression` or `visit_Call`, etc. methods, those nodes were passed to the `NodeWalker.generic_visit()` method instead, which processes each field and calls `self.visit()` for any further nodes.

Comment: What do you mean that I'm supposed to write `visitor` method myself? I don't see any code for that in the guide.

Comment: @JeanoErmitaño: The `NodeVisitor` class is meant to be a baseclass for code that is analysing AST trees. It is a *framework class*, not something that is used directly without subclassing. So yes, you are supposed to write `visitor_*` functions yourself. You only need to use this if you are analysing Python code for some other task.

Comment: @JeanoErmitaño: See [this example in a random Python project](https://github.com/pziegfeld/OpenMDAO-Framework/blob/master/openmdao.util/src/openmdao/util/dep.py#L87); that project is interested in `import` and `class` statements and collects information about those.

Comment: I was referring to the `visitor` in `visitor = getattr(self, method_name, self.generic_visit)` and `return visitor(node)`. How come this `visitor` gets assigned some attribute and then acts like a method accepting a `node`?

Comment: @JeanoErmitaño: `getattr()` looks up attributes on the first argument, so `self` here. The attribute name is the string found in `method_name`, and if not found, `self.generic_visit` is returned. Methods are just attributes on the instance, so if `method_name` is set to `visit_BinOp`, then `self.visit_BinOp` is returned provided it exists. That's a method you can call.

Comment: @JeanoErmitaño: There are almost certainly better ways of achieving the same result in C#. It may be that you need to define a base implementation for each node type, so you can constrain those down to specific `AST` subclasses. I'm a little puzzled why you are re-implementing a Python library in C#, I'm sure C# has their own ways of implementing a tree visitor pattern.

Comment: @JeanoErmitaño: in other words: rather than try to implement the Python code one-on-one in C#, try to understand what the *intent* is of the code and implement *that* in C#. I note that the article you are reading explains why `visit()` uses `getattr()`: *Second, instead of a giant if statement in the NodeVisitor’s visit method like this...*. This is all possible because Python is dynamically typed and highly introspectable. C# won't (easily) let you do the same, so perhaps in C# you just have to build a giant `if` statement.

Comment: So it's not as simple as translating Python code to C#, you mean I have to learn the visitor pattern and create my own code?

Comment: That's exactly what I'm saying.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your question about [`getattr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr): This is just a function which returns an attribute with a given name (in the 2nd parameter) of an object (in the 1st parameter) and with a fall back (in the 3rd parameter) if there is no attribute.

So in your case `getattr(self, method_name, self.generic_visit)` it tries to get an attribute with the name `method_name` from itself. And if it doesn't exist it uses `self.generic_visit`. Now if `method_name` is `"visit_BinOp"`, it'll try to get `self.visit_BinOp`, and if that doesn't exist it'll instead get `self.generic_visit`.

In the end, without running the code, it cannot be determined what it'll return or what type `visitor` is going to be. It could be anything in theory, but usually it is a method. But that is a difference from Python and C#, that the type of a variables in Python depends on what is assigned to it. You can do the following without an issue:

```
i = 42
# i is now an int, but you can easily overwrite it with a string
i = "Hello World"
```

And the same is with `node`, in theory it can be anything, but if used correctly it'll be a subclass of `AST`.

Comment: If `node` can be any type, how come the author of the guide was able to use `node.op.type` in the `visit_binOp`. I assume with this that a `node` contain the `op` operation token. Would `node` be a class then, or a subclass of `AST`?

Comment: The author assumes that the correct type was given as a parameter, and if that wasn't the case Python would throw an error (e.g. if the `node` has no `op` attribute or the `node.op` has no `type` attribute).

Comment: I need to explicitly define what a `node` is in C# unlike in Python, thus I'm asking what data type is `node`.

Comment: In that case it is actually `AST`. This is also why this class exists.