# Visitor Pattern for Interpreter - Invoking method based on instance type

Tags: java

The below code does not compile due to incompatible types obviously. However, I am trying to do something similar. In order to get this to work to my knowledge, I would have to take the superclass and check what type it is and use a switch case or a nasty if else set. I can leverage polymorphism here and place the visit method in ASTNode and override it in each sublcass, however, that is putting logic in the ASTNode class when I want to make sure this remains in the Interpreter class.

```
public class Test {

    private class ASTNode{

    }
    private class ExprNode extends ASTNode{

    }
    private class VarNode extends ASTNode{

    }
    private class Interpreter{

        public Interpreter(ASTNode node){
            this.visit(node);
        }

        public void visit(ExprNode node){

        }
        public void visit(VarNode node){

        }

    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ASTNode node = new ExprNode();
        Interpreter interpreter =  new Interpreter(node);
    }
}
```

I am building an interpreter and I am using the Visitor Pattern for the Interpreter. There is a visit method for each type of node. In the example I am working from which was written in python, they use a getattr method that dispatched the call to the right method based on the subclass. I do not know of anything similar in Java.

Lastly, if I were to use polymorphism here I would be defining different visit methods for the Interpreter and Symantic Analyzer in the ASTNode classes. I like the idea of have Interpreter logic in the interpreter class but I would hate to have a huge switch case based on the subclass type.

Any ideas here? Maybe I am missing an easy technique.

Comment: https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/visitor/java/1

Comment: Can the `visit` method not be on the `Node` classes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The point of the visitor pattern is to replace the "huge switch" with polymorphism by handling the visitor invocation on the individual subclass. It doesn't mean that the *logic* is contained in the subclasses, rather that's defined on the visitor class. Here's how that would look in your example:

```
interface NodeVisitor {
    void visit(ExprNode node);
    void visit(VarNode node);
}

class Interpreter implements NodeVisitor {
    @Override
    public void visit(ExprNode node) {
        // custom logic here
    }

    @Override
    public void visit(VarNode node) {
        // custom logic here
    }
}

private class ASTNode {
    public abstract void accept(NodeVisitor visitor);
}

private class ExprNode extends ASTNode {
    @Override
    public void accept(NodeVisitor visitor) {
        visitor.visit(this);
    }
}

private class VarNode extends ASTNode {
    @Override
    public void accept(NodeVisitor visitor) {
        visitor.visit(this);
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    ASTNode node = new ExprNode();
    node.accept(new Interpreter());
}
```

Comment: perfect explanation!! Thanks so much!