# How do I list a function's parameters using ast?

Tags: python, abstract-syntax-tree

I'm using the ast module to parse docstrings in a Python module to turn our docs into read the docs format. I'm using the following to get the function names and docstrings into a list of dicts which the rest of my code works well with. I'm looking for something to get the parameters of the function as well:

```
good_file = (file for file in os.listdir() if file[-3:] == '.py' and file != '__init__.py')

functions = []

for file in good_file:
     with open(file, 'r') as f:
         module = ast.parse(f.read())

     for node in module.body:
         if isinstance(node, ast.FunctionDef):
         entry = {"docs": ast.get_docstring(node), "fn_name": node.name, "params": ???}

         functions.append(entry)
```

I'm looking for what I can use to fill in the function's parameters into the dict. Thanks!

Comment: Did you try looking at `node.args`?

Comment: Do this interactively.  Try `dir(node)` and see what attributes are available and just poke around.

Answer (score 15):

The [*Abstract Grammar* section of the `ast` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#abstract-grammar) tells you where to find the parameter definitions in a `FunctionDef` node:

> ```
> stmt = FunctionDef(identifier name, arguments args,
>                    stmt* body, expr* decorator_list, expr? returns)
> ```

In the parameters is a sequence of `type name` entries; the names become attributes on the node. The types are further covered in the documentation (with several 'builtin' types listed at the top, which are reflected as Python strings and integers). Types with `*` after them are sequences (lists), a question mark means they can be set to `None`.

So each `FunctionDef` node has `name`, `args`, `body`, `decorator_list` and `returns` attributes. The `args` attribute is a new node, of type `arguments`, also documented:

> ```
> arguments = (arg* args, arg? vararg, arg* kwonlyargs, expr* kw_defaults,
>              arg? kwarg, expr* defaults)
> ```

so `FunctionDef.args.args` is a list of arguments, each an `arg` object, etc.

`arg` is documented as

> ```
> arg = (identifier arg, expr? annotation)
>        attributes (int lineno, int col_offset)
> ```

where `identifier` is a built-in type, so just a string here.

You probably want to look at the [`ast.dump()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.dump), which will give you a quick overview of an AST node:

```
>>> source = """def foo(bar, baz=None, *args, **kwargs): pass"""
>>> module = ast.parse(source)
>>> ast.dump(module)
"Module(body=[FunctionDef(name='foo', args=arguments(args=[arg(arg='bar', annotation=None), arg(arg='baz', annotation=None)], vararg=arg(arg='args', annotation=None), kwonlyargs=[], kw_defaults=[], kwarg=arg(arg='kwargs', annotation=None), defaults=[NameConstant(value=None)]), body=[Pass()], decorator_list=[], returns=None)])"
```

From there you can then explore and further 'dump' information to get to the actual data you need:

```
>>> function = module.body[0]
>>> ast.dump(function.args)
"arguments(args=[arg(arg='bar', annotation=None), arg(arg='baz', annotation=None)], vararg=arg(arg='args', annotation=None), kwonlyargs=[], kw_defaults=[], kwarg=arg(arg='kwargs', annotation=None), defaults=[NameConstant(value=None)])"
>>> function.args.args
[<_ast.arg object at 0x109852fd0>, <_ast.arg object at 0x109852ef0>]
>>> [a.arg for a in function.args.args]
['bar', 'baz']
```

The defaults are attached to the last names in the `args` or `kw_args` sequences (`defaults` for `args`, `kw_defaults` for `kwonlyargs`); a list of N defaults attached to the last N names in `args` or `kwosnlyargs`. Any catch-all names (`*args` and `**kwargs` in my example) are listed separately.

Comment: @MartijnPieters but when I try to print the `defaults`, I am getting `ast` object like this `[<_ast.NameConstant object at 0x000001CF53C28E10>, <_ast.Str object at 0x000001CF53C28E48>, <_ast.Num object at 0x000001CF53C28E80>]`. Currently I am getting value using this logic `print([b.__dict__.get(b._fields[0]) for b in node.args.defaults])`. But I am sure there will be a better way to get the default arguments. Any idea?

Comment: @TonyMontana sorry, I can’t really make out what you are asking or what you expected to find. Comments are not really suitable for this kind of assistance either though, perhaps a new question would be a better fit. At any rate, for AST traversal, I recommend you use the `ast.walk()` and `ast.NodeVisitor` utilities (I have an [example of the latter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40342936)).