# pyparsing generic python function args and kwargs

Tags: python, pyparsing

I'm trying to create a parser for generic Python functions separating out `args` and `kwargs`.  I've looked through the [examples](https://github.com/pyparsing/pyparsing/tree/master/examples) but couldn't find one that helps.

Here is an example of what I'd like to parse and what I'd like the output to be after I parse with `parseString().asDict()`.

```
example = "test(1, 2, 3, hello, a=4, stuff=there, d=5)"
results = xxx.parseString(example).asDict()
results
{'name': 'test', 'args': ['1', '2', '3', 'hello'], 'kwargs': {'a': '4', 'stuff': 'there', 'd': '5'}}

or 
example = "test(a=4, stuff=there, d=5)"
results = xxx.parseString(example).asDict()
results
{'name': 'test', 'args': '', 'kwargs': {'a': '4', 'stuff': 'there', 'd': '5'}}

or
example = "test(1, 2, 3, hello)"
results = xxx.parseString(example).asDict()
results
{'name': 'test', 'args': ['1', '2', '3', 'hello'], 'kwargs': ''}
```

Both the arguments and keyword arguments should be optional and I'm ignoring for the moment super generic `*args`, `**kwargs` and input nested lists, etc.  I managed to get something working when there are only args or kwargs but fails when I have both.

```
import pyparsing as pp

LPAR = pp.Suppress('(')
RPAR = pp.Suppress(')')

# define generic number
number = pp.Regex(r"[+-~]?\d+(:?\.\d*)?(:?[eE][+-]?\d+)?")

# define function arguments
arglist = pp.delimitedList(number | (pp.Word(pp.alphanums + '-_') + pp.NotAny('=')) )
args = pp.Group(arglist).setResultsName('args')

# define function keyword arguments
key = pp.Word(pp.alphas) + pp.Suppress('=')
values = (number | pp.Word(pp.alphas))
keyval = pp.dictOf(key, values)
kwarglist = pp.delimitedList(keyval)
kwargs = pp.Group(kwarglist).setResultsName('kwargs')

# build generic function
fxn_args = pp.Optional(args, default='') + pp.Optional(kwargs, default='')
fxn_name = (pp.Word(pp.alphas)).setResultsName('name')
fxn = pp.Group(fxn_name + LPAR + fxn_args + RPAR)
```

And the results

```
# parsing only kwargs
fxn.parseString('test(a=4, stuff=there, d=5)')[0].asDict()
{'name': 'test', 'args': '', 'kwargs': {'a': '4', 'stuff': 'there', 'd': '5'}}

# parsing only args
fxn.parseString('test(1, 2, 3, hello)')[0].asDict()
{'name': 'test', 'args': ['1', '2', '3', 'hello'], 'kwargs': ''}

# parsing both
fxn.parseString('test(1, 2, 3, hello, a=4, stuff=there, d=5)')[0].asDict()
...
ParseException: Expected ")", found ','  (at char 19), (line:1, col:20)
```

If I check parsing just the `fxn_args`, I get the `kwargs` simply missing altogether

```
# parse only kwargs
fxn_args.parseString('c=4, stuff=there, d=5.234').asDict()
{'args': '', 'kwargs': {'c': '4', 'stuff': 'there', 'd': '5.234'}}

# parse both args and kwargs
fxn_args.parseString('1, 2, 3, hello, c=4, stuff=there, d=5.234').asDict()
{'args': ['1', '2', '3', 'hello'], 'kwargs': ''}
```

Comment: Have you considered using [the `ast` module](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/ast.html#module-ast)? It lets you parse Python from within Python and returns a nice data structure - Python's abstract syntax tree. It's part of the standard library, so no 3rd-party libraries required.

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51271587/how-do-i-list-a-functions-parameters-using-ast

Comment: I've never used the `ast` module.  I'll take a look at it but I'm not actually trying to parse real python code, so it might be overkill.  I'm really just working with simple strings that contain generic functions calls, as part of larger program of parsing various string expressions into items that translate into queries (or functions) to run.  Can `ast` parse simple strings?

Comment: @havok2063, of course, it can parse any valid Python syntax: function calls, variable definitions, `if` statements, whole Python programs. It also builds the AST for you, so the only thing left for you to do is to traverse it. I think using a 3rd-party parser to parse what your Python interpreter is already capable of parsing is the real overkill. Although `ast` can only parse valid Python code, so if you decide to diverge from it sometime, you'll have to use a different parser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If both args and kwargs are present, your parser is tripping over the ',' between them.

You can see this for yourself using pyparsing's runTests method:

```
fxn.runTests("""\
    # parsing only kwargs
    test(a=4, stuff=there, d=5)

    # parsing only args
    test(1, 2, 3, hello)

    # parsing both
    test(1, 2, 3, hello, a=4, stuff=there, d=5)
""")
```

Will print:

```
# parsing only kwargs
test(a=4, stuff=there, d=5)
[['test', '', [['a', 4], ['stuff', 'there'], ['d', 5]]]]
[0]:
  ['test', '', [['a', 4], ['stuff', 'there'], ['d', 5]]]
  - args: ''
  - kwargs: [['a', 4], ['stuff', 'there'], ['d', 5]]
    - a: 4
    - d: 5
    - stuff: 'there'
  - name: 'test'

# parsing only args
test(1, 2, 3, hello)
[['test', [1, 2, 3, 'hello'], '']]
[0]:
  ['test', [1, 2, 3, 'hello'], '']
  - args: [1, 2, 3, 'hello']
  - kwargs: ''
  - name: 'test'

# parsing both
test(1, 2, 3, hello, a=4, stuff=there, d=5)
                   ^
FAIL: Expected ")", found ','  (at char 19), (line:1, col:20)>Exit code: 0
```

Most easily fixed with:

```
fxn_args =  args + ',' + kwargs | pp.Optional(args, default='') + pp.Optional(kwargs, default='')
```

You might also find that identifiers are not just Word(alphas), but also '_' and numeric digits. There is an identifier expression in the pyparsing_common namespace class included with pyparsing:

```
ppc = pp.pyparsing_common
ident = ppc.identifier()
number = ppc.number()
```

`number` will also do auto-convertion to int or float.

Comment: Nice.  I had no idea about the `runTests` method.   That's really nice for debugging. I had an idea on what the syntax error was but couldn't come up with the right fix.  Your `fxn_args` fix does the trick.   I didn't know about `identifier` and `number`.  Those might be good adoptions. I'll check it out.  Thanks!